# Have iframe load when visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page with about 100 videos on them (youtube) loading an iframe. They are all in an accordion style menu, I was wondering if there was a way to have them load when the accordion is open or the iframe is visible on the page. Right now it takes up way too much memory and lags the page a lot.

Comment: Can you identify when each the accordion item is open? Or can you provide the JS that opens each item and some HTML that shows at least one of the items in the accordion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You haven't shown any code that allows us to include this in your code.

Don't set the src of the video, store it in data

```
<iframe src="about:blank" data-src="http://youtu.be/etc"></iframe>
```

Using whatever triggers the accordion, $(this) being that accordion item

```
var $iframe=$(this).find('iframe');
if ($iframe.data('src')){ // only do it once per iframe
    $iframe.prop('src', $iframe.data('src')).data('src', false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Okay so it will go as follow:**

> **HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Video 1</h3>
    <div class="content" data-link="//www.youtube.com/embed/nlcIKh6sBtc">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>

    <h3>Video 2</h3>
    <div class="content" data-link="//www.youtube.com/embed/My2FRPA3Gf8">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>

    <h3>Video 3</h3>
    <div class="content" data-link="//www.youtube.com/embed/CevxZvSJLk8">
        <iframe width="200" height="200" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **javascript**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("content"), bubbles = false;

var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(attrModified);
});

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    observer.observe(elements[i], { attributes: true, subtree: bubbles });
}

function attrModified(mutation) {
    var contentStyle = mutation.target.getAttribute("style");
    var IsVisible = contentStyle.indexOf("block") != -1;
    if(!IsVisible){
        var $currentIframe = $(mutation.target).children("iframe");
        $currentIframe.attr("src", "");
    }
    else{
        var link = $(mutation.target).data("link");
        var $currentIframe = $(mutation.target).children("iframe");
        $currentIframe.attr("src", link);
    }
}

$("#accordion").accordion();
```

**Example:** [AccordionLoadFrame](http://jsfiddle.net/sEXDA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to do this, you can set the src property of the iframe, that points to the videos, on the event that is triggered when the accordion is opened. I haven't worked in a while with the accordion, but pretty sure there is a init event for it.

Comment: Well, it isn't always god to just write code out there for someone to use. The benefiting factor is research, and give them where to look. My opinion. When code is published, and they need help with a section of it, then you post the code fix or completion. When the question is asking a direction, I give them a direction. Better than wasting a comment to have no reason, but dispute somthing. :)

Comment: Here, check if the iframe is clickable, is so, then that means it is loaded. Then, set content of the accordion triggering event.  Post some of the code, and something specific can be written for you to see how to incorporate this methodology.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are finding answer to this question, another solution would be adding lazyload effect to content. [jQuery LazyLoad Any](https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any) library can be used to achieve the same. Library also has eg. of rendering [YouTube Video](http://emn178.github.io/jquery-lazyload-any/samples/youtube/).

Comment: does not work for me in uk-accordion. all iframes are loaded when the page is opened.