# Bootstrap - Load (onpress) Tab/Dropdown Content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I've made a really simple dropdown menu with a list of 'videos' that will be loaded by a iframe. But, the page is loading the iframes right when you get in.

What's the easiest way to make it load the iframe only when I press a 'category' on the dropdown?

This might be really easy to do, but I'm still learning and I can't make it work...

My HTML:

```
<div class="tabbable">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills" id="myTab">
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Videos 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Video 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Video 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O1KW3ZkLtuo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xEhaVhta7sI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
```

And CSS :

```
.scrollable-menu {
height: auto;
max-height: 200px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Appreciate your help! - Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8nujau0/)

Comment: look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482601/have-iframe-load-when-visible

Comment: @ikeMiguel So I'll have to use JS? How to I set the "$" on a dropdown and I can call the iframe? Sorry for the 'noobish'...

Answer (score 0):

Like on the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482601/have-iframe-load-when-visible), don't set the src of the video. Instead, store it in data.

An example would be:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O1KW3ZkLtuo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Using the `show.bs.tab` event trigger of bootstrap you should be able to do this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var open_tab = $(e.target).attr('href');
  var iframe = $(open_tab).find('iframe')
  var iframe_src = iframe.data('src')
  if(iframe.attr('src') == ""){
      iframe.attr('src', iframe_src)
  }
})
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8nujau0/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! However I can't make it work on Wordpress, but it should be working correctly, right?

Comment: You're welcome. It should have no problem with Wordpress when you placed the src to data-src and placed the javascript correctly. Does it still load the same way as before?

Comment: It doesn't show anything at all, that's the issue but it seems the problem it's Wordpress, not sure why tho...

Comment: Are the codes rendered properly when you view the source code?